# Not able to start DSE Server

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I've installed DataStax Enterprise with simple install settings. I am trying to use Cassandra, so I started the server using :

```
bin/dse cassandra
```

But it stucks showing an error. Below is the data I am getting after running the above command : (Also the system.log file content)

```
INFO  15:39:51,502  DseModule.java:88 - Loading DSE module
INFO  15:39:51,635  DseConfigYamlLoader.java:38 - Loading settings from file:/home/ishan/dse/resources/dse/conf/dse.yaml
INFO  15:39:52,107  DseConfig.java:372 - Load of settings is done.
INFO  15:39:52,109  DseConfig.java:392 - CQL slow log is enabled
INFO  15:39:52,111  DseConfig.java:393 - CQL system info tables are not enabled
INFO  15:39:52,112  DseConfig.java:394 - Resource level latency tracking is not enabled
INFO  15:39:52,112  DseConfig.java:395 - Database summary stats are not enabled
INFO  15:39:52,113  DseConfig.java:396 - Cluster summary stats are not enabled
INFO  15:39:52,113  DseConfig.java:397 - Histogram data tables are not enabled
INFO  15:39:52,114  DseConfig.java:398 - User level latency tracking is not enabled
INFO  15:39:52,114  DseConfig.java:400 - Spark cluster info tables are not enabled
INFO  15:39:52,149  YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85 - Configuration location: file:/home/ishan/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  15:39:52,212  YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85 - Configuration location: file:/home/ishan/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  15:39:52,341  Config.java:451 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=640; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=64; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=true; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=/home/ishan/dse/commitlog; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=null; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@180da663; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; encryption_options=null; endpoint_snitch=com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch; file_cache_size_in_mb=512; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=/home/ishan/dse/hints; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; incremental_backups=false; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=127.0.0.1; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=128; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=null; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; min_free_space_per_drive_in_mb=50; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; num_tokens=1; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=DISABLED; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=127.0.0.1; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/home/ishan/dse/saved_caches; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=127.0.0.1}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; trickle_fsync=true; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  15:39:52,345  DatabaseDescriptor.java:323 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  15:39:52,372  DatabaseDescriptor.java:437 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 495MB
INFO  15:39:52,373  DatabaseDescriptor.java:441 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 495MB
INFO  15:39:52,376  DseDelegateSnitch.java:44 - Setting my workload to SearchAnalytics
INFO  15:39:52,405  YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85 - Configuration location: file:/home/ishan/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  15:39:52,408  DseDelegateSnitch.java:46 - Initialized DseDelegateSnitch with workload SearchAnalytics, delegating to com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch
WARN  15:39:52,436  DatabaseDescriptor.java:603 - Only 10748 MB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
INFO  15:39:52,454  YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85 - Configuration location: file:/home/ishan/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  15:39:52,456  DseConfig.java:434 - Cql solr query paging is: off
INFO  15:39:52,460  DseConfig.java:449 - Server ID:C4-8E-8F-8F-4E-57
INFO  15:39:52,931  GraphYamlConfigurationReader.java:185 - Loading graph settings from file:/home/ishan/dse/resources/dse/conf/dse.yaml
INFO  15:39:52,931  GraphYamlConfigurationReader.java:189 - Opened stream on file:/home/ishan/dse/resources/dse/conf/dse.yaml
ERROR 15:39:53,061  DseModule.java:98 - org/apache/spark/util/ByteBufferInputStream. Exiting...
```

Can anyone guide me here ? Thanks in advance.
And my cassandra.yaml file content is (without comments) -

```
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
hints_directory: /home/ishan/dse/hints
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000
max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
role_manager: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseRoleManager
roles_validity_in_ms: 2000
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
 - /home/ishan/dse/data
commitlog_directory: /home/ishan/dse/commitlog
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
saved_caches_directory: /home/ishan/dse/saved_caches
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:
- class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
  parameters:
      - seeds: "127.0.0.1"
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: true
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 127.0.0.1
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: 127.0.0.1
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 64
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 640
unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold: 10
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
internode_encryption: none
keystore: resources/dse/conf/.keystore
keystore_password: cassandra
truststore: resources/dse/conf/.truststore
truststore_password: cassandra             [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
client_encryption_options:
enabled: false
optional: false
keystore: resources/dse/conf/.keystore
keystore_password: cassandra [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
internode_compression: dc
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800
gc_warn_threshold_in_ms: 1000
enable_user_defined_functions: false
enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: false
windows_timer_interval: 1
otc_coalescing_strategy: DISABLED
```

and the contents of dse.yaml file is -

```
max_memory_to_lock_fraction: 0.20
hive_meta_store_enabled: true
authentication_options:
enabled: false
default_scheme: kerberos
other_schemes:
    - internal
scheme_permissions: true
allow_digest_with_kerberos: true
plain_text_without_ssl: warn
transitional_mode: disabled
role_management_options:
mode: internal
authorization_options:
enabled: false
transitional_mode: disabled
kerberos_options:
keytab: resources/dse/conf/dse.keytab
service_principal: dse/_HOST@REALM
http_principal: HTTP/_HOST@REALM
qop: auth
ttl_index_rebuild_options:
fixed_rate_period: 300
initial_delay: 20
max_docs_per_batch: 200
thread_pool_size: 1
solr_resource_upload_limit_mb: 10
shard_transport_options:
type: netty
netty_server_port: 8984
solr_encryption_options:
graph_events:
ttl_seconds: 600
cql_slow_log_options:
enabled: true
threshold: 2000.0
minimum_samples: 100
ttl_seconds: 259200
cql_system_info_options:
enabled: false
refresh_rate_ms: 10000
resource_level_latency_tracking_options:
enabled: false
refresh_rate_ms: 10000
db_summary_stats_options:
enabled: false
refresh_rate_ms: 10000
cluster_summary_stats_options:
enabled: false
refresh_rate_ms: 10000
spark_cluster_info_options:
enabled: false
refresh_rate_ms: 10000
spark_application_info_options:
enabled: false
refresh_rate_ms: 10000
driver:
    sink: false
    connectorSource: false
    jvmSource: false
    stateSource: false
executor:
    sink: false
    connectorSource: false
    jvmSource: false
histogram_data_options:
enabled: false
refresh_rate_ms: 10000
retention_count: 3
user_level_latency_tracking_options:
enabled: false
refresh_rate_ms: 10000
top_stats_limit: 100
quantiles: false
solr_indexing_error_log_options:
enabled: false
ttl_seconds: 604800
async_writers: 1
solr_slow_sub_query_log_options:
enabled: false
ttl_seconds: 604800
async_writers: 1
threshold_ms: 3000
solr_update_handler_metrics_options:
enabled: false
ttl_seconds: 604800
refresh_rate_ms: 60000
solr_request_handler_metrics_options:
enabled: false
ttl_seconds: 604800
refresh_rate_ms: 60000
solr_index_stats_options:
enabled: false
ttl_seconds: 604800
refresh_rate_ms: 60000
solr_cache_stats_options:
enabled: false
ttl_seconds: 604800
refresh_rate_ms: 60000
solr_latency_snapshot_options:
enabled: false
ttl_seconds: 604800
refresh_rate_ms: 60000
node_health_options:
uptime_ramp_up_period_seconds: 86400
dropped_mutation_window_minutes: 30
enable_health_based_routing: true
async_bootstrap_reindex: false
lease_metrics_options:
enabled: false
ttl_seconds: 604800
system_key_directory: /home/ishan/dse/resources/dse/system_keys
config_encryption_active: false
config_encryption_key_name: system_key
initial_spark_worker_resources: 0.7
spark_shared_secret_bit_length: 256
spark_security_enabled: false=
spark_security_encryption_enabled: false
hadoop_options:
spark_encryption_options:
enabled: false
keystore: .keystore
keystore_password: cassandra
key_password: cassandra
truststore: .truststore
truststore_password: cassandra
dsefs_options:
enabled: false
keyspace_name: dsefs
work_dir: /home/ishan/dse/dsefs
public_port: 5598
private_port: 5599
data_directories:
    - dir: /var/lib/dsefs/data
      storage_weight: 1.0
      min_free_space: 5368709120
audit_logging_options:
enabled: false
logger: SLF4JAuditWriter
retention_time: 0
cassandra_audit_writer_options:
    mode: sync
    batch_size: 50
    flush_time: 500
    num_writers: 10
    queue_size: 10000
    write_consistency: QUORUM
system_info_encryption:
enabled: false
cipher_algorithm: AES
secret_key_strength: 128
chunk_length_kb: 64
hive_options:
insert_max_retries: 6
insert_retry_sleep_period: 50
internode_messaging_options:
port: 8609
graph:
adjacency_cache_clean_rate: 1024
adjacency_cache_max_entry_size_in_mb: 0
adjacency_cache_size_in_mb: 128
analytic_evaluation_timeout_in_minutes: 10080
gremlin_server_enabled: true
index_cache_clean_rate: 1024
index_cache_max_entry_size_in_mb: 0
index_cache_size_in_mb: 128
max_query_queue: 10000
realtime_evaluation_timeout_in_seconds: 30
schema_agreement_timeout_in_ms: 60000
schema_mode: Development
system_evaluation_timeout_in_seconds: 180
window_size: 100000
ids:
    block_renew: 0.8
    community_reuse: 28
    consistency_mode: GLOBAL
    id_hash_modulus: 20
    member_block_size: 512
listener:
msg:
    graph_msg_timeout_in_ms: 5000
observer:
shared_data:
    refresh_interval_in_ms: 60000
gremlin_server:
    port: 8182
    threadPoolWorker: 2
    gremlinPool: 0
    maxContentLength: 65536000
    maxChunkSize: 4096000
    maxInitialLineLength: 4096
    maxHeaderSize: 8192
    maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
    resultIterationBatchSize: 64
    useEpollEventLoop: false
    serializers:
        - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistry], classResolverSupplier: com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.tinkerpop.io.DseClassResolverProvider }}
        - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistry], classResolverSupplier: com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.tinkerpop.io.DseClassResolverProvider }}
        - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
        - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistry] }}
        - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV2d0, com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.tinkerpop.io.DseGraphIoRegistryV2d0] }}
        - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistry] }}
    scriptEngines:
        gremlin-groovy:
            config:
                compilerCustomizerProviders:
                    "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.customizer.ThreadInterruptCustomizerProvider": []
                    "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.customizer.InterpreterModeCustomizerProvider": []
```

Comment: Try turning on Debug logging in the logback.xml in the cassandra conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced same problem... If you saperately installed Spark, pls remove (unset SPARK_HOME variable) and then try restarting it should work. 
Let us know how it goes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather start it as `service dse start` if it's installed as a service

else, what is in your yaml file [`/home/ishan/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml`]

Do you want to start Spark as well? otherwise change it in `/etc/default/dse` and set `SPARK_ENABLED=0`

Comment: I've updated my query with cassandra.yaml file content. Please check. And yes I need spark as well.

Comment: first thing, change the `  - seeds: "127.0.0.1"` to `  `- seeds: <IP ADDRESS>` - also make sure to remove " " from the seeds. Here is mine:

`- seeds: 10.15.xx.xx, 10.15.xx.xx`

Comment: did you restart the server as well? what happens when you try and start it with `service dse start -f `

Comment: On `sudo service dse start -f` , I am getting `Failed to start dse.service: Unit dse.service not found.`
And I cannot even start the dse server. This is the actual problem.

Comment: what guide are you using ? give me an ls of the `/home/ishan/dse/resources/cassandra` directory. Also sound like you installed the tarball version right?

Comment: These are the contents of my `/home/ishan/dse/resources/cassandra` directory - 
`bin  CHANGES-DSE.txt  CHANGES.txt  conf  CONTRIBUTING.md  doc  lib  LICENSE.txt  NEWS.txt  NOTICE.txt  pylib  README.asc  tools`
And I downloaded its installer i.e. - `DataStaxEnterprise-5.0.7-linux-x64-installer.run` and installed it.

Comment: I used this link for installation - `https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/install/installNoSudoDse.html`

Comment: edit your first post and include the output of system.log an output.log , if you don't know where that is, use `find / -name system.log`

Comment: All that data mentioned in the question already (where I am getting error) is the content of system.log file

Comment: look for a "caused by" section of the error log. also post your dse.yaml file contents.

Also see in the debug.log file if anything stands out there

Comment: There is no caused by section in any log file. debug.log file has the same content as the system.log file. See the updated question for dse.yaml file content.